# Solr 4.7 using 'solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory' highlighting issue

Tags: solr

Can someone help me with highlighting issue that I'm having when I search for 'cars' it is highlighting 'car','cars' expected behavior and also all the words that start with car for example 'cards','carriers' etc.

user requirement is we don't want to highlight anything that starts with 'car'?? here is my schema.xml

```
<analyzer type="index">
       <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" 
                pattern="[({.,\[\]})]" replacement=" "/>
   <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
   <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"/>
   <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" preserveOriginal="1"  catenateAll="1"  />
   <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="true"/>
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15"/>
   <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you're indexing `cards` with an edgengramfilter, you get the tokens `c`, `ca`, `car`, `card` and `cards`. When you're then searching for `cars` and *you have the same edgengramfilter* for the field, you`ll search for any document matching any of the tokens`c`,`ca`,`car`, and`cars`.

The solution is to either drop the edgengramfilter when indexing (so that you don't get a hit for `c`, `ca` or `car`), or use a different field for highlighting (with `hl.fl`) that only have standard tokenization / whitespace tokenization applied, together with possibly a stemmer (I'd go with `solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory` to only remove plural indicators).

Comment: Thank you for the response, it works if I remove edgengramfilter but it stopped searching all the relevant results, user wants to see all the relevant results when searching for cars - first all occurences of car,cars and all other that starts with car how can we achieve this?

Comment: As mentioned - you can use a different field for highlighting than for searching. Use one without the edgengram for highlighting (and give it in `hl.fl`), and one for searching with edgengram. You can use `copyField` to index the same content into both fields.

Comment: I tried that too both the solutions worked Thank you, one more issue when I use different field I get all the desired results but results are not in way user wants, for exmaple - searching for 'cars' brings cars,carts,cards,car is there a way to show the most relevant one first like cars,car,cards...etc??

Comment: Use a third field (or in this case, maybe just the field you're using for highlighting) with a more constrained form (i.e. more exact hits, without edgengram), then apply boosting to that field. With `edismax` you'd do this with `qf=field1^10 field2^5 field3` to give `field1` 10x the weight of `field3`, etc. (the last boosted one, `field3` should be the one that generates most irrelevant hits).

Comment: Matt - This is really helpful thank you so much for your response will try this today.

Comment: Hi Matt - I have one more question, when i do copy field I don't use all the filters that I use on original field instead I'm only using one filter 'SnowballPorterFilterFactory' I have issues with highlighting works in most of the cases but for the terms that I added in sysnonyms.txt and I included 'SynonymFilterFactory' and 'StopFilterFactory' on original field doesn't work for copy field,can you help me with this issue.. I hope I'm making sense?

Comment: copyField happens before any processing, so the value is processed all by itself for the second field. Whatever happens in the first field definition does not affect what happens in the second field definition.

Comment: Hi MatsLindh, I have a different question regarding highlighting, Here is my requirement when someone searches for "hand bags" this should return "hand bags" ,"handbags","hand-bags" . so for that to work I have updated the synonyms.txt and it works as expected but my problem is highlighting when document for example: "My bags are packed and my hand-bags are also packed". In this particular case search result brings this document because it contains "hand-bags" but also highlights "bags" is there a way we can restrict this additional word highlighting?   Thank you in advance!